# Controlling starting point for transformation CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div containing text which transforms/transitions with CSS when a link is hovered. However, I don't understand why it works, and when I play with the values it changes the divs ending position (absolute centred both vert and horiz). I want to change the divs STARTING position

HTML

```
<div class="bg-img" style="background-image:url('...');">

   <a href="#" class="linkage"></a>

   <!-- Put cat div overtop article -->
   <div class="cat-cell">
        text is here
   </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.cat-cell {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 9;
  opacity: 0; 
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 60%;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;    
  transition: all 0.5s ease;    
}

.linkage:hover + .cat-cell {
  opacity: 1;

  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

The .cat-cell div fades in and moves up from the bottom of the parent div a certain amount to the center of the parent div. I want to shorten the amount it moves up (looks like it moves up around 100px, I want it only to move up 50 to get to the center). But when I change any values it no longer centres in the parent at the end of the transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The starting position of your transition is determined by the initial state (the .cat-cell CSS).

The `translateY(-50%)` moves the .cat-cell up by 50% of its own size whenever .linkage:hover is "active".

So `.linkage:hover + .cat-cell` sets the end state of your element, while `transition: all 0.5s ease` tells the browser to display a transition may a property's value change (in this case the `opacity` and the `transform`).

Also, it is better to not use `transition: all 0.5s ease`, because the browser will attempt to transition all properties of the element. Use `transition: transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease` instead.

Comment: so how can I change it's start/initial state while still making sure the transition ends where it currently does. Also, changing to transition: transform 0.5s ease; removing the motion completely

Comment: Change the position of your `.cat-cell` (the `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom`) to change the starting position. You might want to change the `translateY` as well to make up for the difference caused by altering the starting position.

In this very case you might want to keep the `transition: all` because of the vender-prefixes (-moz, -o-). Just want to tell you it is considered bad habit in most cases.

Comment: follow up question, I can't seem to find the right combination. setting the translate to 40% and increasing the top: % to something like 60%. or vice-versa seems to screw with the end position regardless

Comment: The `top` position is relative to its parents size while `translateY` is relative to the size of the element itself.
You need to know the size of both in order to determine the right values.
Try (temporarely) setting both in `px` to get a feeling for it ;)
Or use `top` instead of `translateY` to make it easier on yourself.